# C++ Templates and Factories

Tags: c++, templates, reference, design-patterns, factories

I've been playing with C++ for a few years now, and want to become adept at using 
and factories.  Are there some good web tutorials and/or textbooks that cover this well?

I started programming prior to the wide use of the term "patterns" ('80's)... but when I first saw the term I recognized the "pattern" of it's usage.  A good reference/resource for various useful patterns would also be useful to me as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about design patterns?

Answer (score 3):

The links in this forum post will help you a ton:

[Forum Post](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=327982)

Answer (score 3):

Read books of Herb Sutter like **Exceptional C++** or **C++ Coding Standards**,
books from Scott Meyers, like **Effective C++**.

For different patterns read **Design Patterns** by the Gang of four (Gamma, Helm, Johnson, Vlissides), the **Advanced C++ Programming Styles and Idioms** by James O. Coplien is also good.

If you want to go deeper - like metaprogramming, take the **Modern C++ Design** by Andrei Alexandrescu.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean book for C++ Templates and Design patterns ?

Then, my choice:

- C++ Templates : [C++ Templates The
  Complete Guide](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=EotSAwuBkJoC&dq=C%2B%2B+Templates+The+Complete+Guide+%2B+josuttis&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=iwLZM21oeg&sig=0v97fIH9aFLXQfQH6MjyY64iuRk&hl=en&ei=79OtSpXNKeKRjAeZ9-zhBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by Josuttis
- design Patterns: [Head First design
  patterns](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=HeadFirst+design+patterns&ei=H9StStz7IomGzATKntXuBA#v=onepage&q=HeadFirst%20design%20patterns&f=false)